# Redirecionar para página de erro ao entrar no catch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou com uma dúvida quanto a uma possível melhoria no método quando ocorre um erro em um `Action` e redireciono para uma página de erro. No momento, faço dessa forma na `Action`:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            //Um código qualquer aqui 
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Erro");
        }
    }
```

Ou seja, caso dê um erro de código eu redireciono para a `Action Index`do `Controller Erro`. **Acontece, que esse método que eu utilizo tem um problema. Quando a `View` que vou retornar está dentro de um `Modal`, a página de erro é meio que exibida dentro do `Modal`, ficando com o layout totalmente desconfigurado**.

Com isso, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma melhor ou mais correta que ao lançar uma exceção de erro, redirecione para a página correta.

Comment: Como você está chamando o Modal, poderia adicionar essa parte?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Isso vai depender muito das regras do seu sistema, mas geralmente o comum é deixar que o erro ocorra na aplicação para que o seu servidor retorne um código 500 quando acontecer algum erro.

Assim como uma página não encontrada retorna um status code 404, quando um erro acontece internamente na sua aplicação a requisição retorna um status code 500.

Esses erros já redirecionam o client para uma página default, mas você pode personalizar para quais páginas o client vai ser redirecionado no caso de algum erro no servidor através do `web.config` da sua aplicação adicionando essas configurações:

```
<customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="~/Error/500">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/404" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/500" />
</customErrors>
```

Você pode adicionar configurações para todos os status codes onde `redirect` é a `Action` para qual o client vai ser redirecionado.

A propriedade `defaultRedirect` é a `Action` para qual o client vai ser redirecionado caso o error status code não esteja especificado.

Utilizando essa abordagem a sua aplicação vai gerar logs de erro no seu servidor quando algo acontecer, isso pode vir a ser muito útil caso precise verificar algo.